# What is causing this weird output?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
void doPlayerMove(void)
{
    bool moved = false;

    while (!moved) 
    {
        printf("\nWhere is the piece you want to move?(rc):");
        int r = getchar() - '0';// gets the row number
        int c = getchar() - '0';// gets the column number

        printf("%d:%d", r, c);// prints the chosen row/column

        clearInput();
        printf("\nWhere is the space you want to move to?(rc):");
        int r2 = getchar() - '0';
        int c2 = getchar() - '0';

        printf("%d:%d", r2, c2);

        ...
    }
}

void clearInput(void)
{
    while(getchar() != '\n');
}
```

this is the output i get:

```
Where is the piece you want to move?(rc):51
5:1
Where is the space you want to move to?(rc):40
4:00
```

Whats up with the extra 0? Does anyone see where the problem is?

Comment: from the next `printf` call ? :D

Comment: c00kie may be onto the problem; if you change `%d:%d` to `%d:%d\n` does the extra zero go away?

Comment: Call `clearInput();` after the second input.

Comment: If you add `\n` at the end of the strings that you print, the second zero will likely appear on the next line :)

Comment: Problem solved, it was some output from some function i was calling in the `...` sorry for the false alarm!

Comment: In the future, please post as complete examples as possible. Also see http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP says in a comment:

> Problem solved, it was some output from some function i was calling in
>   the ... sorry for the false alarm!